# get local time for different location in flutter

Tags: flutter

is there a simple way to get time for a different location than the current location  in flutter ?

for example the current location is set to **Japan,Tokyo** and I want the time in **Turkey, Istanbul** from the system itself not from API

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/timezone 
Step 1: download `2019c.tzf` from https://github.com/srawlins/timezone/tree/master/lib/data 
Step 2: put `2019c.tzf` to `assets` directory

[image]

Step 3: Edit `pubspec.yaml`

[image]

working demo

[image]

code snippet

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/2019c.tzf');
  initializeDatabase(byteData.buffer.asUint8List());
  runApp(MyApp());
}

...

final detroit = getLocation('America/Detroit');
final us = getLocation('US/Pacific');
final tokyo = getLocation('Asia/Tokyo');

nowDetroit = new TZDateTime.now(detroit);
nowUs = new TZDateTime.now(us);
nowTokyo = TZDateTime.now(tokyo);
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart';
import 'package:timezone/standalone.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/2019c.tzf');
  initializeDatabase(byteData.buffer.asUint8List());
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  TZDateTime nowDetroit;
  TZDateTime nowUs;
  TZDateTime nowTokyo;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    final detroit = getLocation('America/Detroit');
    final us = getLocation('US/Pacific');
    final tokyo = getLocation('Asia/Tokyo');

    nowDetroit = new TZDateTime.now(detroit);
    nowUs = new TZDateTime.now(us);
    nowTokyo = TZDateTime.now(tokyo);

    _counter++;
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(' America/Detroit ${nowDetroit.toString()}'),
            Text(' US/Pacific  ${nowUs.toString()}'),
            Text(' Asia/Tokyo  ${nowTokyo.toString()}'),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```